# DateTime ToString(“dd/MM/yyyy”) returns dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have also tried shielding the '/' symbol in the formatting string, but it didn't quite work.  My final goal is to get the date with the '/' symbols as separators. I guess I can use `DateTime.ToString(“dd/MM/yyyy”).Replace('.', '/')`, but that feels a bit excessive.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `/` character in date/time format strings stands for "whatever the date separator of the format provider is". Since you do not supply a format provider `Thread.CurrentCulture` is used, and in your case the current culture uses `.` as the date separator.

If you want to use a *literal* slash, place it inside single quotes:

```
dateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Alternatively, you could specify a format provider where the date separator is `/`:

```
dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

All of the above is [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator).

**[See the difference in a live example](http://ideone.com/gp9RE4)**.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the *why* part of the question (i.e. says that "/" is the culture-specific separator) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it always depends on the starting culture

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way [`ToString` works by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx), in accordance with the current culture:

> This method uses formatting information derived from the current
>   culture.

So, override that:

```
string date = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it always depends on the starting culture