# DatePicker dd/mm/yyyy format showing dd-mm-yyyy, why

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I have `DatePicker` in Xamarin.Forms. It is showing date in mobile dd-mm-yyyy format. How can I change it to dd/mm/yyyy format

This is m code

```
<DatePicker Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Date="{Binding SelectedFromDate}"                  
</DatePicker>
```

In above code I am using `Format="dd/MM/yyyy"` still it is different format in Android mobile

[image]

Comment: You need to set a culture. See a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15273288/4739420).

Comment: What is exasctly your problem? In your title :  dd/mm/yyyy format showing dd-mm-yyyy, so it is displaying what is supposed to?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro - my problem is I need date format is dd/mm/yyyy but it is showing dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @r15 I have added an answer look at once.

Comment: @r15 Hi , does this `Format="dd/MM/yyyy"` not working ?

Comment: @r15 Hi , have you solved this ? Maybe this is result from Mobile' Settings. Have a try this in your device' setting. **Settings->Date&Time->Select Date Format->18/06/2019**

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - Due to something I got involved in other work. When I do the same i'll let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @r15 Great ,if solved let me know that :)

Answer (score 3):

if you want mm/dd/yyyy format, change the code to :

```
<DatePicker Format="MM/dd/yyyy" Date="{Binding SelectedFromDate}"                  
</DatePicker>
```

For other type of formats can be reference from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Comment: Pl see my updated question. I need dd/mm/yyyy format. but it is showing dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: weird, i tried Datepicker without Format parameter and still have dash `/` display. Have you tried remove the `Format` ? Is it still `-` without the `Format` ?